# Algorithm: is there any way to pack image segments?

Tags: algorithm, opencv, image-processing

I am looking for a way to pack a binary image like the following one:

[image: binary image]

to something like:

[image: packed binary image]

in OpenCV, I know that there are many algorithms for rectangle packing but I am looking for the most efficient packing method for segments

Comment: How are you allowed to rearrange segments (translation, rotation, reordering, etc.)?

Comment: You probably want to reduce the segments to polygons to make the problem easier to work with. You’re then still left with a hard problem, though. Some ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6864382/7328782

Comment: "nesting" (the technical term) is an optimization problem, meaning it's ***hard*** (technical term) to find the optimum, but there may be heuristics and approximation algorithms and simplifying situations. please do the research (literature, implementations) -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nesting_(process) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nesting_algorithm -- the usual problems exist in 2D (any 2D stock cutting) and 3D (e.g. 3D printing)

Comment: @templatetypedef translation, without rotating, resizing or anything else, just moving